# How to print every 8-letter string with uppercase and lowercase letters? (In python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

my code:

```
import time
letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"] 
passwd = ""
while True:
    for a in range(0,51):
        passwd+=letters[a]
        for b in range(0,51):
         
            passwd+=letters[b]
            for c in range(0,51):
          
                passwd+=letters[c]
                for i in range(0,51):
                 
                    passwd+=letters[i]
                    for d in range(0,51):
                       
                        passwd+=letters[d]
                        for e in range(0,51):
                            
                            passwd+=letters[e]
                            for f in range(0,51):
                               
                                passwd+=letters[f]
                                for j in range(0,51):
                                    
                                    passwd+=letters[j]
                                    print(passwd)
                                    time.sleep(0.1)
                                    passwd = ""
```

This is what I want to be outputted:

AAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAB
AAAAAAAZ
.........
zzzzzzzx
zzzzzzzy
zzzzzzzz

What do I need to change?

Comment: Printing those 53 trillion strings with a 0.1 second gap between each one would take over a million years. Perhaps you would like to reconsider your requirements.

Comment: I don't think this makes it a bad question. It can be useful for educational purposes or as some kind of decoration.

Comment: I actually checked, it will "only" take 169,519 years (give or take...)

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be fixed by removing the `passwd`-string and doing `print(letters[a]+letters[b]+...)` in your innermost loop instead.
Having eight nested loops isn't very elegant, though, so here is an alternative:

```
import itertools
import time
from string import ascii_letters

for word in itertools.product(ascii_letters, repeat=8):
    print(''.join(word))
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Then, press Ctrl+c if it takes too long :)

Comment: More simply, `itertools.product(letters, repeat=8)`

Comment: you can get all the letters from string.ascii_uppercase